# Kibana visualizations splitting fields with dashes in them

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am building visualizations in Kibana for AWS CloudWatch metrics, and have run into a bit of an issue creating Metric Tables.. Kibana is splitting my fields that contain dashes (instance ID, region, etc..)

Rather than having an individual row with an instance ID, for example, i-7bb06dzz, it is creating 2 rows: i & 7bb06dzz. "i" displays the aggregate count of all other fields. If I add a second split with the region, this is duplicated for every set of characters in the region name separated by dashes as well. (us , east, and 1  instead of just us-east-1).

I tried to post a screenshot, but my reputation is not high enough to do so..
Here are my visualization settings:

```
Metrics: Metric (Count)

Aggregations: 
Split Rows: Terms: InstanceID: Top 5: Order by metric:Count
Split Rows: Terms: Region: Top 5: Order by metric:Count
```

No Advanced Settings have been specified. I was able to get a reasonable looking list by only specifying InstanceID, and excluding the pattern "i"... however, it doesn't do me a lot of good when I can't display the region next to it. Both values are indexed as strings and were recorded in ElasticSearch with double quotes around them.

Any recommendations on how to display the fields as intended would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because Elasticsearch "analyzes" the field for the individual tokens in it. Logstash will store fields in both the `fieldname` and `fieldname.raw` fields - the latter is unanalyzed and will behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Chris,
I had just found the solution on github, and you are absolutely correct. I'm not using LogStash, so I posted the mappings from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elasticsearch/logstash/v1.3.3/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-template.json , and it duplicated my fields as raw. 

Once I adjusted the visualizations to the raw format, I got the intended results.

Comment: If you don't need both the analyzed and not_analyzed versions, then don't create the .raw field and only set the main field to not_analyzed.  Depending on your usage, this can be done in a mapping or template.